# What is render path?

Tags: graphics, rendering

What is "render path"? Who invented this term?

I can suppose that this thing mean something one from the list below:

- The thing which shows which rendering technique should be used (e.g. forward/deffered rendering)
- Module for rendering lines and curves
- Description how shaders should be connected in mutlipass render to reach the goal of some render FX.

For what this term is stand for? Thanks

Comment: Never heard of it. What's the context? If it's specific to Unity, you might want to take a look at the [doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingPaths.html). (Thanks to @MartinSojka for the tip.)

Comment: What is the context of the terminology in question? There are several different things the term could mean, as you noted.

Comment: Don't give up on this, @bruziuz.  Josh and Alexandre are giving you feedback on how you can improve this question.  I answered "something", but maybe not your intended question.  Give us some context to help us understand where you heard this, and how we can add to the body of community knowledge.

Comment: I heard about it at the kitchen. And I assumed that it is exist well-known graphic term for it. Sorry, but I can't provide any more detailed context((

Answer (score -1):

I think it's more commonly called a history tree by 3d modelers.  I've heard of render path and render tree to describe the ORDER in which render steps occur.

For an image render example:  If you blur 10%, then add a sparkle light source looks different than if you do those two events in the opposite order.

In a class once taught, I showed a 3d model example where the model looks different if you start with a rectangular solid and then fillet first and hollow as the 2nd step, versus if you hollow 1st and fillet the outside second.

In the image below, you can see difference in the shape when you change the ORDER of the model render history.

[image]

Here's the terms that I think are close synonyms in 3d modeling:

- History Tree
- Model Tree
- Render Tree
- Render Path